# Parse Windows sdk api + proxies

Tags: parse-platform

with regards to the parse windows api, windows 8, vb.net

how does parse work through proxies from say an app behind a corporate proxy?

will it auto detect per windows user say the IE proxy/network connection settings?

can you in the parse code set a custom proxy host, port, proxy username & password auth before connecting to it?

if so, how in vb.net?

where in your code can you specify the proxy settings etc and is their a reference somewhere to this info as i can't seem to find it?

hope that makes sense

thx

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for our setup. You can use the default proxy settings from IE by adding the following to your App.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"></defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
    ...
</configuration>
```